# Passed props from another component cannot be read

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props

**I am trying to pass a prop to another component, but it is just returning a blank object**

I have already tried making a constructor but it didn't worked.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const greeting = "Welcome to React";
    return (
      <div>
        <Greeting greeting={greeting} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>{this.props.greeting}</h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Greeting />, document.getElementById("root"));
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have introduced in the DOM render of react the child component instead of the App class which is the one that passes the title to it.

Take a look at this solution: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-o6rtk

**You must put App instead of Greeting**

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: oh thanks. sorry for this stupid question, I'm just a newbie

Comment: Don't worry we've all been rookies once, and those who haven't, we still have a lot to learn @JeffreyDelosSantos

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to render the Greeting component in the root div, delete that line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to render the parent component in ReactDOM to pass the props to the child component.

You can have a look in the practical demo of your problem and solution in the link below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-saflfb